# cors amazon s3 benchmarking by Jmeter

Tags: amazon-s3, automation, jmeter

@All
Can you guys please suggest, how can we use J-meter to benchmark the performance of uplaod content to cors amazon s3.

we are using plupload module in drupal. We need to click on "Add Files", and select the file.
Then, the request will go to cors amazon s3 server.

We want to user J-meter for benchmarking with a set of users.

Answer (score 1):

This should be your starting point,

https://github.com/bigstepinc/jmeter_s3_custom_sampler

Comment: Hi Sumant, Welcome to stackoverflow!  Please see "How Do I Write a Good Answer?" http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all I would recommend recording your file upload action via [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)
2. Once you have the script skeleton you need to care about authentication and correlation. See i.e. A [JMeter test plan for Drupal](http://www.metaltoad.com/blog/jmeter-test-plan-drupal) for details.
3. As soon as you are able to replay your test script up to "Add files" page check out [Performance testing: Upload and Download Scenarios with Apache JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-performance-test-upload-and-download-scenarios-apache-jmeter) for a set of instructions on proper simulating file upload.
4. You may with to parametrize files along with MIME types so not only one file could be uploaded during performance test. Take a look at [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) element.

Comment: Yes,its seems to be ideal steps for performance testing.
I already followed the above mentioned steps. But, it did not work work for me.
Actually, J-meter is placing a direct request to amamzon s3 while recording the script.
And I am not supposed to pass the key to access the amazon se files directly using J-meter for security reasons.
So, dropped this performace plan.
Anyways, reply to this post is highly appreciated
Thanks!!!!